# nineoldAndroid AnimationListenerAdapter

Tags: android, android-animation, android-library, android-compatibility

I used the android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter class in my code to listen to animations.
Example :

```
downView.animate().translationX(-mViewWidth).setDuration(mAnimationTime).
setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {                     
@Override
    public void onAnimationStart(
    Animator animation) {
    boolean real_dismiss = true;
    performDismiss(
//some code
)
    }
```

I used the backward compatibility lib by nineoldandroids, the animations work fine, but i am getting the following error, that does not let me run my code, at my listener:

The method setListener(Animator.AnimatorListener) in the type ViewPropertyAnimator is not applicable for the arguments (new AnimatorListenerAdapter(){})

The code was working fine when I was using the API level 11.
My old import statements:

```
//import android.animation.Animator;
//import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
//import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
```

My new import statement :

```
import com.nineoldandroids.animation.*;
import com.nineoldandroids.*;
```

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem and found [Jake Wharton's implementation](https://github.com/JakeWharton/SwipeToDismissNOA/blob/master/src/com/example/android/swipedismiss/SwipeDismissTouchListener.java#L156) of `SwipeDismissListener`:

On Line 156, Jake is using `com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(View arg0)`

to perform the same function.

Therefore, all you need is to change your code to something like this:

```
animate(downView)
.translationX(-mViewWidth)
.setDuration(mAnimationTime)
.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {  

@Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    boolean real_dismiss = true;
    performDismiss(//some code)
}
```

And there shouldn't be any error.

Comment: any idea why onAnimationStart(Animator animation) doesn't get called even though the animation is effectuated ?

Comment: @Lucas that answer was long time ago, could u be more specific about the issue? thx

Comment: it worked when I used public void onAnimationStart(com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator animation). There was maybe a confusion of which library to use

Comment: Just don't forget to add `import static com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animate;`.